# Find the path to an executable

Tags: ocaml

How can one find the absolute path to an executable based on the PATH environment variable (e.g. based on the environment variables for `/bin/sh`)?

In other words, is there a function, e.g. `program_path "cal"` that returns `"/usr/bin/cal"`?

The reason for asking this question: some functions in the OCaml library (e.g.  `Unix.execvp`) are able to only take the program's name (and the function will search for the program on its own). I was wondering whether or not this search functionality is available to the user.

Comment: `Unix.execvp` just calls out to the [`execvp` POSIX function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp), and I don't think there is even a POSIX function that allow you to search the path. You can perhaps call out to the `which` command though. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/which

Comment: On Unix, I think you could try 'system' and try to use system's implementation of 'which', and match on ENOENT, in which case you have to 'getenv' "PATH" and search through the comma separated folders and take the first one (i.e. your own 'which' implementation). I think any third function would have to implement it like this on top of module Unix.

Comment: You might be interested in [`whereis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whereis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [fileutils](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/fileutils/) library, that implements a POSIX compliant file utilities, including the `which` utility, the one that you're looking for. E.g.

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "fileutils";;
# FileUtil.which "cal";;
- : FilePath.filename = "/usr/bin/cal"
```